# Closed subschemes defined by sections of a line bundle

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

I am encountering the following question now.

Consider a smooth and irreducible projective variety over complex numbers. Let $L$ be an ample, globally generated line bundle on $X$. For $r$ satisfying $2\leq r\leq h^0(X,L)$ consider general $r$ dimension subspaces $V\subset H^0(X,L)$.

Consider the zero locus of these spaces, these are closed subschemes $Z_V$ whose ideals are the images of $V\otimes L^{-1}\rightarrow O_X$.

Since we choose $V$ to be general enough the closed subschemes $Z_V$ have codimension exactly $r$ in $X$.

I am interested in understanding whether these closed subschemes move in a family. More precisely if we take $V$ and $V'$ general $r$ dimensional subspaces, then will $Z_V$ and $Z_{V'}$ have the same Hilbert polynomial?

What is the Hilbert polynomial of such a $Z_V$.

If $Z_V$'s have the same Hilbert polynomial, then so will their ideal sheaves. So they will also move in a flat family.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Inside $G(r,h^0) \times X$ you can form the family whose fibre over an $r$-dimensional subspace $V$ is the closed subscheme $Z_V$. By generic flatness there will be a dense open subset in $G(r,h^0)$ over which this is flat, hence any two subschemes which are fibres over points in the open subset will have the same Hilbert polynomial.

Comment: @potentially dense, will the dense open subset over which the family is flat contain all such subschemes of codimension $r$?

Comment: I believe so, but there is something to check, namely that the total space of the family over that open subset is not too singular. I don't see how to do that right now, so my argument currently gives a weaker result than Lvovski's.

Comment: @potentiallydense,  for the family you suggested, the maximal open set where the family is flat is the open subset of the grassmanian such that the fibre subschemes have codimension $r$. Because by Lvovski's argument, all the fibre subschemes have the same Hilbert polynomial. Isn't that right?

Comment: That's right: if you know the fibres have the same Hilbert polynomial, then the family is flat. I was suggesting that one could _deduce_ constancy of the Hilbert polynomial by showing (in another way) that the family is flat, but Lvovski's argument seems simpler.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe the answer is yes. If your $V$ is spanned by the sections $s_1,\dots,s_k$, then locally they form a regular sequence, so you can form a Koszul complex, which induces an exact sequence
$$
0\to L^{\otimes(-r)}\to(L^{\otimes(-r+1)})^r\to (L^{\otimes(-k+2)})^{r(r-1)/2}\to \dots\to (L^{-1})^r\to \mathcal I\to 0,
$$
where $\mathcal I$ is the ideal sheaf of $Z_V$. It is obvious from this exact sequence that Hilbert polynomial of $\mathcal I_V$ is an alternating sum of Hilbert polynomials of the other terms of the sequence, which is independent of the coice of sections provided they cut out a subscheme of codimension $r$.

Comment: Thanks Serge Lvovski. The argument seems to use only the fact that the sections come from the same line bundle and cut a subscheme of codimension $r$. Is that correct. Even the fact that $Z_V$ may or may not be smooth is not used?

Comment: Also do you mean $s_1,s_2,..,s_r$? Since $V$ is an $r$- dimensional vector space. Also what is $k$ in the exact sequence?

Comment: Yes, I mean $s_1,\dots,s_r$, sorry for the typo.

Comment: Thanks! Can you suggest any reference for the kozul resolution​ of the ideal sheaf? Also what about the question in the first comment?

Comment: One does not need smoothness, one needs teh codimension to be expected (to coincide with the number of line involved). And line bundles may be different, yes.